# svnsync: PROPFIND request failed

Tags: svn, svnsync

I'm desperately trying to backup my google code-repo but since
I'm not too familiar with SVN, I can't get svnsync to work.
I thought that backing up your repo to another repo or dumpfile was an easy
task, but I'm wrong? I would really appreciate tips on how to do this..

What I'm trying to do:

*@shell:~$ svnsync init http://www.*.org/svn/
http://*.goo​glecode.com/svn/trun​k
svnsync: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn'
svnsync: PROPFIND of '/svn': 301 Moved Permanently (http://www.*.org)

What does that mean? And is it possible to fix it?

http://www.*.org/svn/ was created with svnadmin create, ofc.

Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 1):

I would raise this in a comment, but I don't have the points to comment yet.  It looks like at least part of your problem is that your URLs may not be correct.  The 301 is telling you that the resource you expect to find there is not actually there, so I'd start by checking that URL by doing an svn ls on it.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is that you're trying to sync only the trunk.  I don't believe this is supported - svnsync is intended for making a mirror of the whole repo.  You'd need to leave out the /trunk part.  But first you'll need to get your own repo functional.